# Incredibly weird puppeteer behaviour

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I use this code:

```
// <-- add event on top of file
process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, p) => {
        console.error("Unhandled Rejection at: Promise", p, "reason:", reason);
        // browser.close(); // <-- no need to close the browser here
});

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function getPic() {
    try{ // <-- wrap the whole block in try catch
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500}); // <-- add await here so it sets viewport after it creates the page


      //await page.goto('https://www.google.com');  //Old way of doing. It doesn't work for some reason...

      page.goto('https://www.google.com/').catch(error => console.log("error on page.goto()", error));


      // wait for either of events to trigger
      await Promise.race([
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}),
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load'})
      ]);


      await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});
      await browser.close(); // <-- close browser after everything is done
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

getPic();
```

Then the program hangs. After 30 seconds, i get this error:

```
error on page.goto() Error: Navigation T imeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21) at <anonymous>
```

But i also get the picture i requested!

1.So how is it that page.goto() fails but it still gets the picture, which mean that page.goto() actually worked!?
2. What can i do to mitigate this weird error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js and puppeteer promises causing an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50152127/node-js-and-puppeteer-promises-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program hangs because you called `goto` without async-await or promises, then you put it in a race for waitForNavigation, this makes the browser confused because all three line of code is mostly doing same thing on the back. It is trying to navigate and wait for it.

Use async await for promises. Do not call async methods synchronous ways. No matter what, this is how you must use it in your example case.

```
await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
```

If you want to wait until page load, then the goto function has that covered too. You don't need to use the `waitForNavigation` after `goto`.

```
await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {waitUntil: 'load'});
```

There is also `domcontentloaded`, `networkidle2`, `networkidle0` for the `waitUntil` property. You can read more about it in the docs with full explanation.

The reason why screenshot is working properly is because it's getting executed asynchronously but then you are awaiting for the navigation later on.

Here is the code without much complexity and promise race.

```
try{ // <-- wrap the whole block in try catch
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500}); // <-- add await here so it sets viewport after it creates the page
      await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {waitUntil: 'load'})
      await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});
      await browser.close(); // <-- close browser after everything is done
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Here is how it works perfectly on the sandbox. 
[image]

[The puppeteer docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) is a good place to start to learn about this.

Comment: don't you need an async function in order to use await? how did that work for you?

Comment: puppeteer sandbox does that automatically for me, on other cases, I just add them on top level.

Comment: sorry but your code did not work:
Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous>

Not only it did not work but it also didn't manage to download the picture for me.

Comment: The code i posted in my question spews that error but manages to get me the picture at least....
It is an error that i cannot seem to overcome no matter the suggestions.

People downvote and flag this question but at the same time cannot offer any help or understanding on how this is happenning....

Not only that but it's illogical. How come there is a Navigation Timeout Error but it still gets the picture anyway?

Comment: Seriously i am too tired of not figuring this out... I am willing to pay for someone to fix this for me....

Comment: You posted same question three time, so I flagged that as duplicate, but I didn't downvote since it felt you are desperate about the problem. About goto failing and getting screenshot, it's simply how async works as I explained above.

Comment: Try my code on the sandbox at https://puppeteersandbox.com, also the problem simply could be in your computers proxy and puppeteer version. Check those out too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to run the code without any errors (after many weeks). What i did was added a timeout: 0 parameter on my page.goto() method. I don't know how it works, i don't even know what timeout does exactly. But there are no errors. It takes quite some time though (about 30 seconds). I will work on improving it before i post more....